# Nonparametric equivalent for 4x4x2 ANOVA

Tags: r, anova

I calculated a 4x4x2 ANOVA (fully within). However, I would like to apply a non-parametric equivalent (possibly Friedman ANOVA). Is there a package allowing for this? I have not been able to apply the friedman.test() package to it.

Let's imagine we present 21 subjects with 4 names, 2 of which are male and 2 of which are female. We observe brain-responses in 4 different time windows.

Here is some sample data to illustrate this case:

```
subject <- c(1:21)
subject <- rep(subject, 16)

Lisa <- "LISA"
Lisa <- rep(Lisa, 21*4)
Michael <- "MICHAEL"
Michael <- rep(Michael, 21*4)
Dorothy <- "DOROTHY"
Dorothy <- rep(Dorothy, 21*4)
Max <- "MAX"
Max <- rep(Max, 21*4)

Name_ALL <- c(Lisa, Michael, Dorothy, Max)

female <- "FEM"
female <- rep(female, 21*4)
male <- "MAL"
male <- rep(male, 21*4)
Sex_ALL <- c(female, male, female, male)

T1 <- "T1"
T1 <- rep(T1, 21)
T2 <- "T2"
T2 <- rep(T2, 21)
T3 <- "T3"
T3 <- rep(T3, 21)
T4 <- "T4"
T4 <- rep(T4, 21)
Time_ALL <- c(T1, T2, T3, T4)
Time_ALL <- rep(Time_ALL, 4)

EEG_value <- rnorm(n=336, m=9, sd=2)

data <- data.frame(subject, EEG_value, Name_ALL, Sex_ALL, Time_ALL)
```

Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: Using `cbind` instead of `data.frame` means none of your EEG_values have remained numeric. And at the moment you only have a 4 x 2 problem. This concern should have surfaced if you tried to do an ordinary anova. One wonders whether you should go back and review basic R coding methods.

Comment: When you call an old man grumpy you should realize that it may cause performance difficulties.